# Are there positive integers $a$ and $b$ such that $a\neq b$ and $\frac{11ab}{6a+5b}$ is a positive integer?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Are there positive integers $a$ and $b$ such that $a\neq b$ and $\frac{11ab}{6a+5b}$ is a positive integer? I tried using prime factorization but that does not seem to help. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Yes.  One that leaps to mind has $a$ and $b$ both less than $13$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $(a_0,b_0)$ and $d>0$ we define $a=da_0, b=db_0.$

Then $$\frac{11ab}{6a+5b}=\frac{11a_0b_0d}{6a_0+5b_0}.$$

So we can choose $d=6a_0+5b_0,$ or any multiple.

For example, $a_0=2, b_0=1,$ then $d=17,$ and $a=34, b=17$ gives you an answer.

Another example is $a=1, b=12.$ Then $6a+5b=66$ and $\frac{11ab}{6a+5b}=2.$

In general, we can pick $d$ which is a multiple of $$\frac{6a_0+5b_0}{\gcd(11a_0b_0,6a_0+5b_0)}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You want the null vectors of the integer quadratic form
$$ 5bc + 6ca - 11 ab,  $$
so $11ab = 5bc + 6 ca$  with integer $c$

One infinite set of triples, including $(1,1,1),$  is
$$  a = u^2 + 11uv + 24  v^2 ; \; \;  b = u^2 - 9  v^2; \; \;  c = u^2 +5 uv - 24  v^2;  $$ as then

$$ 11ab =  6ac + 5bc = 11u^4 + 121vu^3 + 165v^2u^2 - 1089v^3u - 2376v^4  $$

The intent is that $u,v$ are integers with $\gcd(u,v)=1 $

It is easy to describe  the set of all rational triples $(a,b,c)$  It is difficult to find (and prove)  a complete set of Pythagorean triple type parametrizations  that give all  the **primitive** integer triples. The set of such parametrizations is finite, this is on page 47 in Mordell, *Diophantine Equations*.

Did some checking,  given coprime  $u,v$  the possible values of $\gcd(a,b,c)$  are the divisors of $330= 2\cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 11. $  There are 16 divisors, and we expect to need 16 recipes  of the type shown above.   Can be done, but long.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if a fraction simplifies, <s>it's</s> it could be because each term in its numerator and in its denominator have a common factor.  Can we just set $a=5$ and $b=6$?

$$\frac{11ab}{6a+5b} = \frac{11\cdot5\cdot6}{6\cdot5 + 5\cdot 6} = \frac{11}{2} $$

So that didn't work.  But we made both terms in the denominator the same -- so that now the denominator is divisible by $2$.  What if we make $a=2\cdot5=10$ and $b=2\cdot6=12$?

$$\frac{11ab}{6a+5b} = \frac{11\cdot10\cdot12}{6\cdot10 + 5\cdot 12} = \frac{11\cdot 120}{120} = 11$$

Let's say we had $\frac{11abc}{6a+5b+4c}$.  Set $a=3\cdot5\cdot4$, $b=3\cdot6\cdot4$ and $c=3\cdot 6\cdot5$.  Then

$$\frac{11abc}{6a+5b+4c} = \frac{11\cdot 3^3 \cdot 4^2 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 6^2}{3(3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6)} = 11 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot 6. $$

More generally, given

$$\frac{k\prod_{i\le n} x_i}{\sum_{i\le n}a_i x_i},$$

for fixed constants $k$ and $a_i$, set each $x_i = n \cdot \prod_{j \ne i} a_j$.  Then

$$\frac{k\prod_{i\le n} x_i}{\sum_{i\le n}a_i x_i} = \frac{k \cdot n^n \prod a_i^{n-1}}{n \prod a_i} = k \cdot n^{n-1} \prod a_i^{n-2}.$$